# Lindelöfness in $\omega_1$

Tags: general-topology, ordinals

Is every Lindelöf subspace of the ordinal space $\omega_1$ countable?

Comment: So $\omega_1$ is given the usual order topology, and $Y \subseteq \omega_1$ is a Lindelöf subspace of $\omega_1$?

Comment: Yes, ALL are yes.

Comment: I have completely re-worded the question.  If you disagree, feel free to revert.

Comment: Good work and very appreciated it with your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Y \subseteq \omega_1$ is uncountable, enumerate it is increasingly as $\{ \alpha_\xi : \xi < \omega_1 \}$.  Then $$\mathcal{U} = \{ [ 0 , \alpha_\xi + 1 ) \cap Y : \xi < \omega_1 \}$$ is an open cover of $Y$ without a countable subcover.