# Any Lindelöf subspace of $\omega_1^\omega$ is second countable

Tags: general-topology

Show that any Lindelöf subspace of $\omega_1^\omega$ is second countable.

What I have tried: Suppose that the subspace $Y$ is Lindelöf, then $P_n(Y)$ is countable for any $n\in \omega$, and hence $Y$ is countable Lindelöf space. ([see the link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327241/lindelofness-in-omega-1).) Is every countable Lindelöf space second countable? I'm not sure. I don't know how to continue.

Thanks ahead:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\omega_1^\omega$ is first countable (since $\omega_1$ is), and therefore the subspace $Y$ is first-countable itself.  A countable first-countable space must be second-countable.

---

The [Arens-Fort space](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190495/8348) is an example of a countable (hence Lindelöf) space which is not second-countable (or even first-countable).